# Tankless water heater furthest away room water

Tags: tankless

I have a tankless hot water heater and the 3rd floor of the house takes forever to get hot water.

I was reading some kind of pump could be put in the 3rd floor bathroom to help move the water sitting in the pipes all day?

Comment: what is your question? ... `I was reading ...?` is not a question ... it's a statement

Comment: Does the water run slower on the 3rd floor than the 1st? If not, a pump won't help - you'll still have 20 yards of cold water you need to run first.

Comment: A question mark does not a question make. Please ask an actual question in your question.

Answer (score 3):

A tankless water heater is designed to sit there doing nothing (and saving energy by doing nothing) until the rate of water flow in the hot water pipe reaches a certain minimum value. Then it switches on and starts making hot water.

The rate of water flow from a hot water circulating pump will never reach that minimum value, so it will never switch-on the tankless water heater. The net result for you: no improvement from a hot water circulator pump.

You've just learned one of the major disadvantages of tankless water heaters. If the water heater is far away from the faucet, you'll wait a long time for hot water and you'll waste water down the drain while waiting. There is no way to improve the situation because a tankless water heater is designed to work that way.

Tank-style water heaters contain hot water all the time, so hot water recirculating pumps work great with them, at the cost of a certain amount of energy loss from keeping your hot water pipes hot all the time. But they do conserve water when used with a circulator pump, since it's not necessary to run water down the drain and wait for hot water.

Comment: Yes!  One of the many disadvantages....

Answer (score 0):

What you are hinting at is a circulating pump.  You need to have a loop so that the water circulates continuously, thus providing a quick supply of hot water.

- It would be difficult and expensive to retro-fit it
- It is not economical.  I had put it in my previous house on the plumbers recommendation.  I eventually cut the particle board flooring and short circuited the pipe loop as it was very expensive to run.